# Rendering Twig File In Custom WordPress Function

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

I have the following custom function in **functions.php** to filter WP posts by category using AJAX:

```
function ajax_filter_function() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['categoryFilter'] ) )
        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
        $args = [
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryFilter'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if($query->have_posts()):
        while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();
           Timber::render( 'partial/tease-post.twig', $context );
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else:
        echo '<div class="col-12"><h2>No posts found</h2></div>';
    endif;

    die();
}
```

The AJAX filter perfectly works. What I'm trying to achieve is to render the `Twig` file called `tease-post.twig` from the function. What I'm trying to avoid is to write redundant PHP/HTML code inside the function.

This is the `tease-post.twig` file:

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="card {% for term in post.terms %}{{ 'cat-' ~ term.slug ~ ' ' }}{% endfor %}">
        {% if post.thumbnail.src %}
            <img src="{{ post.thumbnail.src|resize(348, 215, true) }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ post.title }}" />
        {% else %}
          <img src="{{ options.thumbnail.url|resize(348, 215, true) }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ post.title }}" />
        {% endif %}
      <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="h4 card-title">
          <a href="{{ post.link }}" title="{{ post.title }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
        </h2>

        <p class="card-text mb-3">{{ post.preview.length(25).force.end('[...]').read_more(' ') }}</p>

        <a href="{{ post.link }}" title="{{ post.title }}" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">Read More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Right now I can render the HTML part of the Twig file but the values such as `{{ post.title }}` or `{{ post.link }}` don't work.

Any idea on how to achieve this?? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:

```
function ajax_filter_function() {
if ( isset( $_POST['categoryFilter'] ) )
    $context = Timber::get_context();
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = [
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_POST['categoryFilter'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    $posts = $query->posts;
    $context['posts'] = $posts;
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
        $post = Timber::get_post($post->ID);
        $context['post'] = $post;
        Timber::render('partial/tease-post.twig', $context);
    }

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myFilter', 'ajax_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myFilter', 'ajax_filter_function');
```

---

Please feel free to post other solutions if more elegant than mine...personally I'm happy with this solution as it perfectly works... :)